# Question about the abbreviation for 2 instruments in an orchestra score

Tags: strings, instruments, classical-music, orchestra

I'm learning an orchestra score and I'm really new to that. I'm figuring out what instruments are included in this score, and I get most of them (correct me if there is any mistake). However, I'm pretty confused about the `Br.` and `K-B` here.
Also, what is the difference between the two Viol.?

[image: orchestral score with abbreviations]

Comment: What is the composition title and author? In what language or country the score was published? Could it be they are e.g. German abbreviations?

Comment: @user1079505 This is the first symphony of Brahms. Unfortunately, I'm not sure about the language which confused me either :(

Comment: @user1079505 Based on my observation, I guess it's in English or German

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Br. is short for Bratsche, which is german for Viola.

K-B. is short for Kontrabass, which is german for Contrabass a.k.a. Double bass.

The two Viol. parts are both Violins. An orchestra has two sections for the violins (firsts and seconds), these make up the largest portion of the orchestra. Sometimes they will play the same notes but it is very common that they play independently.
(Sometimes these sections will themselves divide (divisi) to play different lines of music)

**P.S.** Since you are new to orchestral scores and german — it's worth pointing out that the clarinets in "B", are really clarinets  in B-flat.  B-flat is B in german, and B is H.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Could you explain what is Hr. (Es) is here? THX!

Comment: @MusicalChicken — You're right that "Hr." is short for Horn (in german and english). Before horns had valves they used a collection of different crooks (tubes of specific lengths). The particular crook that was attached would set the tuning of the instrument to a certain key. The "Es" is german for E-flat. So it's a horn with the E-flat crook attached.

Comment: @MusicalChicken:  Another important thing to remember is that because of the E-flat transposition, the horn staves in that section are actually in unison (not in minor thirds as it might appear.)  If you're not familiar with the concept of "transposing instruments", [Wikipedia has a reasonable summary.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposing_instrument)

Comment: and there are some horrible jokes based on the name "bratsche" .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Hornists, for historical reasons, don't expect to see key signatures, ever. It's just one of those things that drive composers and conductors crazy. I guarantee that the horns are in unison/octaves in mm. 179-180 here; if nothing else, if the C's written in the E-flat horn part were meant to be concert pitch, they would make absolutely no sense against the 2nd violins and violas playing an A-flat minor arpeggio with a C-flat in the middle of it.

Comment: Also, when a part has two players (as in the woodwinds here) and a passage has only one part indicated, you will sometimes see the Italian *a due* (abbreviated a2) to indicate that both players are to play the section.

Comment: @DjinTonic I'm a bit surprised that you mention the woodwinds there, since the instrument where _a 2_ is actually used is the E-flat horns.

Comment: @phoog HaHa. I missed that!

Comment: @PaulZ  You are correct & I apologize for misleading folks.

Comment: As an addendum to the current correct answer The horn named Es is what is known as the English horn which is actually a miss translation of the German word Engel which means Angel. This word is confused because Engels means English while Engel means angel. The English horn does not auctually have anything to do with England. Here is an interesting follow-up question. What key is the piece in and what interval is the transposing instruments operate under?

Comment: An English Horn / Cor Anglais is in the oboe family. One would  be placed directly under the oboe in the score, and it'd be in F. In german it'd be called "Englisches Horn (F)" / "Engl. Hr. (F)".


The horns in this score are (the unrelated brass instrument) the Natural Horn, which are like the modern (French) Horn, but without valves.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace In German it would be "Englischhorn" or sometimes  "Englisch Horn".

Comment: Trivia: The word "Bratsche" comes from the Italian "viola da braccio".

Comment: @PiedPiper — The Dolmetsch Online music dictionary lists both variations:  "Englisches Horn" and "Englischhorn".  But I don't speak german, so I don't understand the significance of the difference in spelling.